# Failed to use typeorm repository to get single record in oracle database

Tags: oracle, repository, typeorm, nest

I'm new with Jest and typeOrm, I'm trying to make a test application and I'm having trouble finding a single record using the 'findOne()' and 'findOneBy()' methods of the typeOrm Repository.
The application always breaks when I try to make a call to the proper endpoint with the message 'SQL command not properly ended'

I'm using an oracle database, I can insert and retrieve all, but I can't retrieve by id or another parameter.

I got to filter a return to a call to get all registered users with the find() method, and i know this is not right.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the problem is the database I'm using that doesn't accept the query formatting raw by TypeOrm.

These methods only work from version 12 of oracledb, and I'm using an old database that is version 11.
The solution was use this instead:

```
this.repo.find({where: {id: id}})
```